# Adding event listeners to metro style grid application?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I have just created a sample grid application using html5 and JavaScript.

What now I want to achieve is to give some animation when user click on group header.

For that I wrote two functions.  One for mousedown event and one for mouse up event:

```
function animateDown() {
    WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown(this);
}
function animateUp() {
    WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerUp(this);
}
```

Now I want add these functions to event listeners for each header.  There are many groups headers and they don't have any ids, just classnames.

So how can I add an eventlistener for all the headings?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation.  So if all elements are in a container you can do:

```
function toggle(event) {
   var header = event.target;
   if (header.classList.toggle("open") {
      WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown(header);
   } else {
      WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown(header);
   }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".container").addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

Comment: thanks :) .It seems like more straight forward way ..But in which page will i give this code? I tried to give this in groupeditempage.js.. but its not working

Comment: I tried to give this code in many place.. but all time container only contain basic html(means with winjs controls declerations  ) even after i assigned every values

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212680.aspx you can pass a collection to `pointerDown` so maybe you can do  `WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown(document.querySelectorAll(".header"))` if each of your headings has a class of header.